# Pdf multiple signatures validation and AcroFields.SignatureCoversWholeDocument method

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

Code for pdf signature validation:

```
    public bool ValidateFileSignatures(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stream);

        AcroFields af = reader.AcroFields;
        var names = af.GetSignatureNames();
        if (names.Count == 0)
            return false; // no signatures

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            if (!af.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(name))
            {
                return false;
            }

            PdfPKCS7 pk = af.VerifySignature(name);

            X509Certificate[] pkc = pk.Certificates;

            if (!pk.Verify())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

When we sign document first time, all works good. But if document signed twice, there are 2 fields with signature, and for first of them method af.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(name) returns false, for second - true. Pdf was signed by methods from [this](https://gist.github.com/alex-t0/f446ccb5ca5e8936b778) example (see  SignTest method). When we sign second time, additional 4-th parameter "append" was passed to this call: `PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', true);`

How to make SignatureCoversWholeDocument method works for all signatures? Or it is impossible and I need remove this check for multiple signed documents?

Comment: There are some conceptual misunderstandings in your code. you might want to read [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) and documents linked from there in addition to @Bruno's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you sign the first time, the first signature covers the whole document. So far so good.

When you sign the second time, the first signature no longer covers the whole document. This should be easy to understand: the first signature doesn't cover the second signature that was added to the document, hence the first signature doesn't cover the whole document. Only the second signature covers the whole document.

You are explaining a problem that isn't a problem, merely a misconception on your part.

Take a look at this image:

[image]

The first signature covers revision 1, but not the whole document.
The second signature covers revision 2. This includes revision 1, but not the whole document. The third signature covers revision 3, including revision 1 and 2. It also covers the whole document.

This is how digital signatures work in PDF. Read the ISO-32000-1 or PAdES standard if you need more info.

Comment: So, if I remove calls to af.SignatureCoversWholeDocument, it is acceptable approach to validate document? Or this can be done better?

Comment: *So, if I remove calls to af.SignatureCoversWholeDocument* - it depends on your use case. often one wants *the outermost signature to cover the whole document*. For a generic solution, though, one should allow for additional revisions adding only validation related information according to PAdES part 4.

Comment: Ok. I think it is acceptable that outermost signature covers whole document, and all other signatures are valid. Thank you guys!